# How to make a Python concurrent Future that signals when a list of Futures has completed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I have a function that submits several tasks to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and return a list of Futures created by each submission:

```
def submit_tasks() -> [Future]:
    futures = []

    for i in range(10):
        future = executor.submit(Task())
        futures.append(future)

    return futures

def submit() -> Future:
    futures = submit_tasks()
    
    # I would like this function to return a single Future that clients can use to check
    # whether all futures in the list have completed. How to do that?
```

I'm on Python 3.8

I would like this function to return a single Future that clients can use to check whether all futures in the list have completed. How to do that?

Comment: use `add_done_callback` on each future and complete the single future when all the futures in the list are done?

Comment: That's what I am thinking, but how do I create a single future that I can then "manually" complete? That's the part I'm having issues with. If you can post this as an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: `Future.set_result`?

Comment: I don't know man, that's why I am asking haha

Comment: did you try using `Future.set_result`?

Comment: actually now that I read further down in the doc I see the thing that does exactly what I was thinking but is already implemented as part of the module :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I was in need for the exact same and tried the accepted answer. But it does not what was asked.*

### My solution to this problem

Because the standard library of python does not provide such a feature I created a little helper class that can combine multiple `Future` objects into one single `Future`. When it completes can be configured with the `complete_when` argument.

**The class:**

```py
import concurrent
from concurrent.futures import Future
from typing import Any

class CombinedFuture(Future[Future | None]):
    """
    This class provides "waiting" mechanisms similar to concurrent.futures.wait(...) except that there is no blocking wait.
    This class extends concurrent.futures.Future and thus it can be used like any other Future.
    You can use the .result() and .done() (and other) methods and also use this class with the aforementioned concurrent.futures.wait function.
    
    This class is especially useful when you want to combine multiple futures with and (&&) and or (||) logic.
    Example:
    Consider you have multiple parallel tasks (as futures) and a future that will be completed once your function should return (canellation_future).
    You want to wait until all tasks finish normally or the canellation_future is completed.
    With the standard python library this is not possible because concurrent.futures.wait(...) can either wait for all futures or one.
    Using ALL_COMPLETED will never work. And FIRST_COMPLETED would return also if only one task_futures was completed.
    The following code uses CombinedFuture to solve this problem.
    
    .. code-block:: python
        
        def create_task() -> Future:
            # TODO add logic that completes this future
            return Future()
        
        # can be completed any time
        cancellation_future = Future()
        task_futures = [create_task(), create_task()]
        
        task_combined_future = CombinedFuture(*task_futures, complete_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
        done, not_done = concurrent.futures.wait([cancellation_future, task_combined_future], timeout=None, return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
        
        if cancellation_future in done:
            print("cancellation_future was completed")
        else:
            print("task_combined_future was completed")
    """

    def __init__(self, *futures: Future, complete_when : int = concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED) -> None:
        self.complete_when = complete_when
        self.futures = set(futures)
        self.completed_futures = set()
        
        super().__init__()

        for future in self.futures:
            future.add_done_callback(self._future_completed_callback)
    
    def _set_result_safe(self, result: Any):
        try:
            self.set_result(result)
        except:
            # this might happen when the future had its result already set
            # this can happen when:
            # a second future completes or multiple at "the same time"
            # or the user called set_result or changed the complete_when attribute. both is not supported
            pass

    def _future_completed_callback(self, future: Future) -> None:
        self.completed_futures.add(future)
        
        if self.complete_when == concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED:
            # no count check required because we only need one and we just added our future
            self._set_result_safe(future)
            return
        elif self.complete_when == concurrent.futures.FIRST_EXCEPTION:
            if future.exception(timeout=0) is not None:
                # future completed with exception
                self._set_result_safe(future)
        # else: should be concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED
        # but we also want this logic in the FIRST_EXCEPTION case
        if self.completed_futures == self.futures:
            self._set_result_safe(None)
```

*(Code originally posted here: https://gist.github.com/Klotzi111/9ab06b0380702cd5f4044c7529bdc096)*

**Usage with the OP's code:**

```py
# add import for CombinedFuture class
def submit() -> Future:
    futures = submit_tasks()
    return CombinedFuture(*futures, complete_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
```

This works because `CombinedFuture` is a sub class of `Future`.

### Why `concurrent.futures.wait` does not work

The question explicitly states that it should be a `Future` that completes when all futures completed.
`concurrent.futures.wait` does not return a `Future`. It just does a blocking wait until all futures given have completed.
It then returns a tuple of two Future lists.
Usage:

```py
done, not_done = concurrent.futures.wait([future1, future2, future3])
# done will containe all 3 futures (because the return_when argument is by default ALL_COMPLETED)
```

### Why it might be needed to get a `Future` instead of using `concurrent.futures.wait`

A `Future` can be passed on to other functions which then can register done callbacks (via `add_done_callback`) or can poll the `Future` for completion (via `done()`).

For other reasons see the documentation of the `CombinedFuture` class.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer, instead of posting links to external ressources